# wordpress W3 Total Cache Fragmented Caching

Tags: wordpress, function

I suppose to add this line to my functions.php

```
<!-- mfunc wpb_set_post_views($post_id); --><!-- /mfunc -->
```

but it produces error , tried to put `<?` but no luck.
any idea why ?

when I open functions.php with dreamweaver to edit it and paste this code , it flag it with red and say syntax error , if I save it anyway then my site crash. Fragmented Caching is to prevent w3 total cache from caching something

here the complete function

```
function wpb_track_post_views ($post_id) {
    if ( !is_single() ) return;
    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;    
    }
   <!-- mfunc wpb_set_post_views($post_id); --><!-- /mfunc -->
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_views');
```

Comment: Question is incomplete, you may want to fix it otherwise it will be deleted.

Comment: I don't think anybody can tell you why, unless you provide more information. What's the error you're seeing? What does wpb_set_post_views do? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.  It should be like this:

```
<!-- mfunc --> wpb_set_post_views($post_id); <!-- /mfunc -->
```